# How do you link your content to the menu tabs

Tags: css

I'd like to create a simple set of tabs with HTML / CSS.
Can someone show me how to display different content under each of the tabs? 
Thanks so much!

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_topnav

Answer (score 0):

The example that you gave was meant as an navigation menu. It links to different pages. That has the effect that the content of the site changes, if that is what you mean.

If you want real tabs, then you have to use Javascript for that. There are a lot of tutorials on how to do that and also a lot of pre-made tabs, so I won't go into that here.

Comment: I can do the Jquery tabs and love them, but was trying to think of a way to create it in-page with CSS and html. What's the issue with that - hiding content?

Comment: Well the hiding isn't the problem, you can do that with `display: none;`, but you have to have some kind of click handler and as far as I know that isn't possible in css. Also, what do you mean by creating them in-page?